# How to chain reactive calls correctly and sequentially

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactor

I am trying to make calls with the following order:

1. save an object
2. publish an object creation event, only if the first step is done
3. Return a Flux list
   What I have currently is following:

   ```
   return dbSaveObject(object) //this returns Mono of created object
       .doOnSuccess(s -> hermes.publishEvent(CREATE)) //publishEvent() here returns Mono<Void>
       .thenMany(Flux.just(object))
   ```

Would this work and publish event as requested, or should I use zipWhen() instead of doOnSuccess()?

Comment: It should work, `zipWith` is overkill since you already have a reference to `object` that needs to be wrapped to flux

Comment: Instead of doOnSuccess you might want to use flatMap especially since the publishEvent method returns a Mono. Also, instead of thenMany you can use thenReturn.

Comment: @MartinTarjányi ```flatMap``` does not want to work because publishEvent returns Mono<Void> It does not want to compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`doOn...` are so-called side-effect operators and should not be used for constructing reactive flows.

In case `publishEvent` returns `Mono<Void>` you could use the following

```
return dbSaveObject(object)
        .flatMap(savedObject ->
                hermes.publishEvent(CREATE)
                        .thenReturn(savedObject)
        );
```

Comment: can I ask a follow up question? When to use Map and when to use flatmap above?

Comment: Simple rule you can use: if operation is async (returns `Mono` or `Flux`) - use `flatMap`, if operation is sync - use `map`